# How to ind only one record with UNION ALL in multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Sorry for the title of the question...

There are multiple records with the same data_name in different tables and with different time_inserts.

I need data_name with older time_insert. I cannot JOIN but only UNION ALL

1. data_name is type VARCHAR2 (255 BYTE)
2. time_insert is type TIMESTAMP (6)

This query works but is slow. I think it is not performing

```
select data_name,token,time_insert,path from table_0 where (data_name,time_insert) in 
(select data_name, min(time_insert) from table_0 where data_name like '%data_name_to_search%' group by data_name) 
union all 
select data_name,token,time_insert,path from table_1 where (data_name,time_insert) in 
(select data_name, min(time_insert) from table_1 where data_name like '%data_name_to_search%' group by data_name)
union all
select data_name,token,time_insert,path from table_2 where (data_name,time_insert) in 
(select data_name, min(time_insert) from table_2 where data_name like '%data_name_to_search%' group by data_name)
```

Comment: If you want help optimizing a query, posting the query plan is generally necessary as a first step.  If you're doing searches with a leading wildcard, though, that's going to force Oracle to do a table scan on all three tables which is unlikely to be fast.  Do you really need the leading wildcard?  If you are only searching for tokens, rather than for the name as part of a larger string, you could potentially create an Oracle Text index and use the `contains` operator instead.

Comment: So, you need 1 row from each table per distinct `data_name`, totalling 3 rows per `data_name`?  And those three rows may have different values for `insert_time`?

Comment: @JustinCave Actually yes, I'm just looking for the token based on the oldest date looking for data_name. Sorry but I have recently started with Oracle SQL and queries and I don't know what is it Oracle Text Indexes. Thank you for your reply, I will look for more documentation

Comment: @MatBailie It is not so. I need to search all tables, for the same data_name but only as a result the record with the oldest time_insert. It could be in any table. However, the result must only be a record.

Comment: @dnlnfr Then your current code doesn't actually work, as it gives one row per table per `data_name` *(or more, if there are multiple rows for the same `(data_name, time_insert)` in the same table)*.

Comment: Be careful. Building an index can have an impact on availability. But this could help with your problem. ``CREATE INDEX table_0_dnti ON table_0(data_name,time_insert);
CREATE INDEX table_1_dnti ON table_1(data_name,time_insert);
CREATE INDEX table_2_dnti ON table_2(data_name,time_insert);``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common practice is to number the rows using `ROW_NUMBER()` and then pick only rows numbers `1`.

The code below `UNION ALL`s the data together, then filters the `data_name` and numbers the rows, then picks only rows numbered `1`.

```
SELECT
  table_id, data_name, token, time_insert
FROM
(
  SELECT
    unioned.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARITITION BY data_name ORDER BY time_insert) AS rn
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 0 AS table_id, data_name, token, time_insert, path FROM table_0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS table_id, data_name, token, time_insert, path FROM table_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS table_id, data_name, token, time_insert, path FROM table_2
  )
    unioned
  WHERE
    data_name like '%data_name_to_search%'
)
  sorted
WHERE
  rn = 1
```

The `table_id` is unnecessary, but helps with debugging, testing, etc.